# Manipulating a cell in excel to count columns in Excel

Tags: excel

Here is my data in Excel, starting from column A to D:

```html
Group Class Time Condition
M Q20 1 Good
M P30 2 Poor
N Q20 1 Poor
M Q20 2 Good
M P30 3 Good
N P30 2 Good
```

I want to count Group and class by two columns Condition and Time  to get different values in the following table

```html
Q20M Q20N P30M P30N
2 0 1 1
```

I have used the following codes to get the above counts

```html
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=M",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">=1",B2:B7,"=Q20")
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=N",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">=1",B2:B7,"=Q20")
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=M",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">=1",B2:B7,"=P30")
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=N",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">=1",B2:B7,"=P30")
```

I want to select a  single cell,  say under this table, to manipulate the Time and to see the counts for each cell. For example, I want to enter a different number of the Times to see how the numbers are changed. The time is now set at>=1.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, don't hard-code the `1`, but use a reference to the cell, e.g. something like this, if your number is in `A10`.

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=M",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">="&A10,B2:B7,"=Q20")
```

Note that you can just use `"Q20"` and `"P30"` and drop the `=`; same for `"M"` and `"Good"`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=M",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">=1",B2:B7,"=Q20")
```

To this:

```
COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"=M",D2:D7, "=Good",C2:C7, ">=" & C8 ,B2:B7,"=Q20")
```

And enter your number in cell C8